# How to add external jar without Eclipse build path option?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar, buildpath

My java file jdbc11.java was compiled successfully with `javac jdbc11.java` command in cmd, after that when I tried to to run `java jdbc11` I got this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc:Driver
```

refering to this code in the file

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

, when I tried it in eclipse ,I added to "Java Build Path" the external jar : `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar` and it run successfully .
in case I didn't fix it with eclipse what should I done in the first try with `java jdbc11` command in order to make work ? 
note: the jar in the same dir with the jdbc11.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the mysql-connector jar to the classpath when you execute your command-line code:

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar;. jdbc11
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class jdbc11`

Comment: I have a feeling that you trying this on a Windows machine so: `java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar;. jdbc11`

Comment: I mentioned in the question cmd, thanks man it worked now can you explain why please ?

Comment: Of Course! The dot (.) means "this location/directory" so you have to include the current location within the classpath to load everything that is around. I've also mentioned "Windows" because the classpath delimiter is not the same for UNIX(:) & Windows(;) systems.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add -classpath in the execute command

java -classpath mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar jdbc11

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class jdbc11

Comment: Do you have package for jdbc11.java, if so, add the package name in front of jdbc11

Comment: Could you please share your jdbc11.java?

Comment: the file in this page: http://www.developer.com/java/data/jdbc-and-mysql-run-the-programs.html 
Please look in the page for "/*File Jdbc11.java"

Comment: if you are working on unix-like platform, please add ":" at the end of above command like this: **java -classpath mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar: jdbc11** if you are working on windows, please add ";" at the end of the command like this: **java -classpath mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar; jdbc11** This is to set the classpath for class jdbc11 during the runtime; BTW, -classpath is the same as -cp

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you allright, what you are missing is a -cp option in your java command line, which is what eclispe would do internally if you were to put it in the build path.

Comment: `java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar jdbc11` tells me "couldn't find the main class jdbc11.