# JSP MySQL Class.forName error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I'm new to JSP. I'm trying to do a basic program of JSP & MySQL connectivity using ADT Eclipse. On running the index.jsp page, I get the following:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 24

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 24

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 24

21: String sql = "select usertype from userdetail";
22: 
23: try {
24: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
25: con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
26: ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
27: rs = ps.executeQuery(); 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:141)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:85)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.30 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
```

I downloaded MySQL Connector J jar and included it in the project

[image: Project Explorer]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: add mysql jar in classpath.

Comment: how to do that? Project properties-> add external jar?

Comment: Yes you are correct . clean and build , run again

Comment: copy jar in web-inf->lib folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add the external jar. Download it and copy in project.

COPY it in `WEB-INF--->lib(folder)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error ,

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

says that it couldn't find the class file .

So you should check for the `mysql jar` to the the project using ,

**Project properties-> add jar**

before that place the jar in folder somewhere inside the project or add through external jar option.

If you already added . trying remove and adding the jar file again

see [how-to-add-mysql-driver-jar-file-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481205/how-to-add-mysql-driver-jar-file-in-eclipse) and [how-to-add-external-jar-without-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024151/how-to-add-external-jar-without-eclipse-build-path-option) for addtional reference