# JSP Class Not Found Exception after using import

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to display table data in JSP

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.mysql.*" %>

<html>
<body>
    <% 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, username, password); 
        String query = "select * from table1";
        Statement stmt = null;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = stmt.ExecuteQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()){

       }
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

It gives cannot find class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Comment: Did you attached the mysql connector jar file to the project classpath?

Comment: Yes, external JAR is added. Also i am able to get the result in a java file. But not in JSP

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP MySQL Class.forName error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649440/jsp-mysql-class-forname-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JDBC Driver is not in the Classpath. Do the following:

1. Put your JDBC Driver in Web-INF/libs
2. Then Right Click on the Jar and do Add to bulid path.
3. Run your application again

Comment: Don't Forget to do the Second Step. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in your classpath.

Simply calling `Class.forName(...)` is not enough.